# Typeset credits at the very end of a document automatically

Tags: floats, positioning, footnotes

I want to print some graphics on the very last page of a document (containing some credits etc.). I don't know the length of the final document since it serves as a template and therefore I need a somewhat more general solution then manually fiddling around with `htbp` qualifiers, `\clearpage` and such. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=0.5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \raggedbottom
    \blindtext\footnote{A footnote.}
    % uncomment to move float to the next page
    %\blindtext
    \begin{figure}[bp!]
        \includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{documentfooter.pdf}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If there is too much text on the last page, the float is moved to the second page. But now it is vertically centered on that page and not aligned at the bottom.

Additionally, the footnote should be typeset above the credits block. Ideally, directly attached to the text above and not to the credits part. In fact, all the content of the document (e.g. other figure, tables, ...) must come before the credits start.

It is not necessary that the credits block is contained in a figure. But that's the only way I could imagine of. Note that the position of page numbers etc. should not be affected by the solution.

Comment: `above` not `about`  in typeset about the document footer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following (somewhat complicated approach) seems to cover all cases:

```
\documentclass{article}

% packages needed only for the purpose of illustration
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=0.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% packages which are actually used for putting the credits box at the right place
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% patch the \Needspace command: not only end the current page in case of
% insufficient space but always create an empty new one 
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@needsp@}{\break}{\break\null}{\typeout{good}}{\typeout{bad}}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%
    % put the credits into a box
    \newsavebox{\credits}%
    \sbox{\credits}{\includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{documentfooter.pdf}}%
    %
    % measure its total height
    \newlength{\creditstotalheight}%
    \settototalheight{\creditstotalheight}{\usebox{\credits}}%
    %
    % check if there is enough space on the current page
    % otherwise insert a page break
    \Needspace{\creditstotalheight}%
    %
    % reduce the size of the current page by the total height of the credits box
    % this is needed since \Needspace doesn't recognize footnotes
    % (they would overlay with the credits box)
    \enlargethispage{-\creditstotalheight}%
    %
    % calculate the upper left corner of the credits block
    % within the text area
    \newlength{\creditsx}%
    \newlength{\creditsy}%
    \ifthispageodd{%
        \setlength{\creditsx}{\dimexpr 1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin \relax}%
    }{%
        \setlength{\creditsx}{\dimexpr 1in+\hoffset+\evensidemargin \relax}%
    }%
    \setlength{\creditsy}{\dimexpr 1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headsep+\headheight
        +\textheight-\creditstotalheight \relax}%
    %
    % typeset the credits at the computed position
    \begin{textblock*}{\widthof{\usebox{\credits}}}(\creditsx,\creditsy)%
        \noindent\usebox{\credits}%
    \end{textblock*}%
    \pagebreak% issue a page break to bring the \raggedbottom into effect on this page
}

\begin{document}
    \pagebreak
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \raggedbottom
    \blindtext\footnote{A footnote.}
    % uncomment to get a two page output
    %\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Result if `text+credits < 1 page`:
[image: Result if text+credits < 1 page]

Result if `text+credits > 1 page`:
[image]

Answer (score 13):

This adds the image as part of the last page foot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=0.5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{empty}
\AtEndDocument{\enlargethispage{-2.5cm}\thispagestyle{credits}}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@credits{%
\def\@oddfoot{\hfill
        \smash{\includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{documentfooter.pdf}}%
        \hfill}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \raggedbottom
    \blindtext\footnote{A footnote.}
    % uncomment to move float to the next page
    %\blindtext



\end{document}
```

---

I (Steven Segletes) didn't feel right making an independent solution based on David's answer, so I am choosing to edit his answer (David, feel free to roll this back if it is no good).  I took David's answer and added the command `\vfill` to the beginning of his`\AtEndDocument` macro.  It takes care of the several use cases discussed, including the one where David's original solution fell short.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=0.5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{empty}
\AtEndDocument{\vfill\enlargethispage{-2.5cm}\thispagestyle{credits}}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@credits{%
\def\@oddfoot{\hfill
        \smash{\includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{documentfooter.pdf}}%
        \hfill}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \raggedbottom
    \blindtext\footnote{A footnote.}
    % uncomment to move float to the next page
    \blindtext



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you uncomment the second `\blindtext`, the footer stays on the first page, but there is still text on the second page. I think this happens because the text fits on the first page, but then `\enlargethispage` is applied causing part of the text to be moved to the second page.

Comment: @porst17 ah that's probably fixable but not sure when I have time, if anyone else wants to take this start and complete an answer feel free....

Comment: I tried the whole day to find a good solution but I could not come up with something useful. I would be very happy to see this working.

Comment: @porst17 I edited David's answer to address your specific deficiency.  Whether it is a general fix, I could not say.

Comment: @steven-b-segletes Sorry for being that late. It seems that the additional `\vfill` makes `\enlargethispage` useless, i.e. the page size is not reduced so that the image overlaps with the text.